# watir getting tag value

Tags: ruby, watir

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="ctl00_SampleContent_FeedbackPanel" style="margin: 10px 0 0 0; padding: 3px; font-style: italic; background-color: #FFFF90;">
<span id="ctl00_SampleContent_FeedbackSelectedIndexChangedLabel">
 You changed your selection to: 
<b>Whiskey</b>
</span>
```

Here is a link top the page: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx.

I selected "Whiskey" from the dropdown and clicked submit.  I need to check if i selected "Whiskey" from the drop down.  So, **how can i get **Whiskey** value** with watir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

browser.b(text: "Whiskey").text
That works